# Fancy indexing automatically completing axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following access of an array a:

```
import numpy as np
j = np.array([[2,1], [0,2], [1,0]])
i = np.arange(j.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis]
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])
a[i, j]
```

Is there a way to do fancy indexing, without using the verbose declaration of i? I am thinking of something along the lines of

```
import numpy as np
j = np.array([[2,1], [0,2], [1,0]])
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])
a[:, j]
```

(which does not result in the same as above).

Comment: At this stage focus more on why the two are different.  This understanding is more important than making the `i` expression prettier.

Comment: To do `francy indexing` you have to create, in one way of other, all of the indexing arrays - with the right shapes.  Here you are trying apply a (3,2) "row-wise", so `i` needs to be (3,1) array.

Comment: `np.take_along_axis(arr, j, 1)` is a newish wrapper for this kind of indexing.